# Apache and PHP - My server returns an empty response without telling me why

Tags: php, laravel, apache, apache2

I've been banging my head all day and can't seem to figure this one out.

I have this code:

```
public function getUsers()
    {
        $company_id = 21;
        $users = User::with('user_details',
            'user_details.department',
            'user_details.payroll_group',
            'user_details.shift_group',
            'user_details.updated_by')
            ->with('deductions')
            ->with('allowances')
            // ->with('shifts')
            ->where('company_id', $company_id)
            ->get();

        foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
            $user->getFirstMedia('images');

            if(isset($user->media[0])){

                $users[$key]->media[0]->url = $user->media[0]->getFullUrl();
            }

            $users[$key]['user_salary'] = UserSalary::getCurrentRate($user->id);
        }

        return response()->json($users, 200);
    }
```

It seems that everytime that `$company_id` has a value of `21` my server always response is empty. BUT if not, it returns as what I've expected.

I tried it in postman, this is the result:

[image]

I also tried running `curl` in my server, it responds this one:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I've checked `laravel.log`, there's no error.
I've checked `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, there's no error also.

I ran out of ideas how to solve this one.

Help me, please! Thanks.

PS: I don't know if i should post this one here or at ServerFault, but here it goes.

Comment: @TsaiKoga - i've checked that one too, nothing that's out of the ordinary in there.

Comment: try to curl http without `s`. is that same?

Comment: @TsaiKoga - yes, it's just the same. response is `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: Try to follow the postman msg. Go to the `setting-general` panel, try to turn off the ssl option

Comment: @TsaiKoga - did that already. I already turned off the "SSL Certificate Verification".

Comment: Is there a proxy open locally?

Comment: @TsaiKoga - no, there is none.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?